# Java/WebDriver element exists but not found in Chrome Visualforce

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, salesforce, visualforce

Recently while running WebDriver tests I've begun receiving TimeoutExceptions even though I know the element is present on the webpage. Here is a code example:

```
// Wait for page to be partially setup
    wait.until(visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("bodyCell")));
```

Here is some of the surrounding HTML for the element I'm looking for:

```
</div></td>
<td class="oRight" id="bodyCell">
<!-- Start page content -->
<a name="skiplink"><img src="/s.gif" height='1' width='1' alt="Content Starts Here" class="skiplink skipLinkTargetInner zen-skipLinkTarget" title="Content Starts Here"/></a>
```

I have used the Chrome console and confirmed that I'm able to find the desired element using CSS, but no matter which By(cssSelector, xpath, id, etc.) I try to use in code it will not find the element.

This is happening on multiple pages, but they are all Visualforce pages. The same code runs on a standard page without issue. This also only applies to running in Chrome, I've run the same test in Internet Explorer and there are no issues on the Visualforce pages.

I've also used driver.getPageSource() to look at the page source and the HTML that is returned is different when I run it in Chrome compared to IE.

I have two main questions:

1. Has anyone else seen a similar issue on Visualforce pages where simple selectors fail to find a WebElement (even though it is absolutely on the page)?
2. Is there any known reason why WebDriver would get the correct version of the HTML in IE, but then get a different version in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating further today I've figured out what was happening. For some reason WebDriver was switching it's focus to an iframe that was on the page. I know this wasn't done somewhere in code because it doesn't differentiate between browsers, they all run the same code without checking if it's a ChromeDriver, InternetExplorerDriver, etc.

The reason the page source was different was because in Chrome it was only returning the source inside the iframe, whereas in Internet Explorer it was returning the full page source.

I fixed this by putting a call to method driver.switchTo().defaultContent() in the constructor of my parent Page Object so that it will always initially start at the top level (even though it should've been doing that to begin with).

I'm not sure why this was happening only on Visualforce pages, but this seemed to fix it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

For #1 - So the element is there by the time you get a query typed into the console, but that does not guarantee that it is present when WebDriver runs that query (it is much faster than us lowly humans). Your wait is waiting for it to be visible...but the NoSuchElementException implies that the element does not yet exist. I'd try waiting for presenceOfElementLocated, instead. Then wait for it to be visible, if needed.

For #2, it is possible (even likely) that the different browsers are receiving different HTML from the server and WebDriver is working correctly.

Comment: #1 Sorry, I misspoke in my original post, it was actually TimeoutExceptions that I was receiving (I've updated my post). The root cause for the timeout was repeated NoSuchElementExceptions. Part of the functionality of waiting for it to be visible is that it first checks if it's present, then checks for visibility. So it was already waiting for the presence of the element, and timedout waiting for it to be present.

Comment: I didn't get a reference to support my above comment, but the method contract for visibilityOfElementLocated can be seen in the following link, and it describes checking for the presence in the DOM: [Selenium API Doc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-)